A dichotomy for everywhere differentiable eikonal functions
Let $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be everywhere differentiable, with $|\nabla f| = 1$ almost everywhere. Is it true that $|\nabla f| = 0$ or $1$ everywhere?

Do you have an example of a function $f\colon\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ that is everywhere differentiable, with $|\nabla f| = 1$ almost everywhere but not everywhere?

@IosifPinelis I do not even have that…

Though I guess the nonexistence of such functions would be an even stronger claim than mine.

@LeoMoos right, but that only works along lines. In $\mathbb R^n$ you get a path integral, along which the derivative can take values other than $1$ even though $|\nabla f| = 1$ a.e.

Whoops, I'd deleted my comment in the meantime. For the record, here is what the original comment said: "Isn't there the trick with the derivative $f'$ of a (not necessarily $C^1$) function $f: \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ retaining the intermediate value property?"

Weil's gradient problem seems to be relevant.

@DaveLRenfro Well that looks just delightful…

The paper Infinite games, Banach space geometry and the Eikonal equation seems to construct a potential example of such functions. @IosifPinelis

Ah indeed, Theorem 4.1 in the paper above is an example.

Apply Theorem 4.2 in this paper (which I learned from your comment) with $U = B_1(- e_1/2)$, and obtain a $\mathbb{Z}^n$-periodic function $u$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $u$ is everywhere differentiable, $\nabla u(x)$ vanishes for $x$ in the boundary of the unit cube, $|\nabla u|\in\bar{U}$ everywhere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\nabla u \in \partial U$ almost everywhere in $\mathbb{R}^n$. In particular, $|\nabla u(x) + \frac12 e_1 | =1$ for almost every $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$. Now let us define $f(x) := \frac12 e_1 \cdot x + u(x)$.  Observe that $\nabla f = \frac12 e_1$ on the boundary of the unit cube and $|\nabla f|=1$ almost everywhere in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Nice find! Unfortunate that my conjecture turns out not to be true though.

Your equation $| \nabla f| = 1$ is a well-studied PDE called the eikonal equation in physics which in turn is perhaps the simplest version of the Hamilton–Jacobi equation.  Suppose $f$ is continuous so that $C = f^{-1}(0)$ is closed. Then $f(x) =\operatorname{dist}(x, C)$ is the distance of $x$ to $C$ provided $f(x) >  0$ and $f$ is smooth at $x$.  This can be seen by observing that the gradient flow of $f$ is given by $\phi_t (x_0) = x_0 + t v$ where $v =\nabla f (x_0)$
provided we are in a small enough neighborhood of a smooth point $x_0$ of $f$. Next observe that $f(\phi_t(x_0)) = f(x_0) + t$.  This process can be reversed. Start with the closed set $C$ and form $f(x) =\operatorname{dist}(x, C)$. Then $f$ solves the eikonal equation where it is smooth.   For example, take $C$ to be two points $A, B$ in the plane.  Then $f$ fails to be differentiable exactly along the perpendicular bisector of the line segment $AB$. Thinking about these examples we see that it is not a good question really, to insist that  $\|\nabla f \|$ be zero where it is not $1$.  (In any case $f$ is certainly not $C^1$ if this happens!)  Rather, such an  $f$ is Lipschitz everywhere and  fails to be $C^1$ along an interesting closed set, the “cut locus” of $C$.
You can see some of this done in the following paper:
Albano, P.; Cannarsa, P.; Nguyen, Khai T.; Sinestrari, C., Singular gradient flow of the distance function and homotopy equivalence, Math. Ann. 356, No. 1, 23-43 (2013), MR3038120, Zbl 1270.35012.

Thanks for the long answer! As bad as an idea it is to think about such functions, they may be relevant for some pretty important stuff. I also think they are interesting in and of themselves.

I agree that such a function would not be $C^1$! However I think the function you give is also necessarily not differentiable everywhere, only almost everywhere.
